# How I Show Windows Registry in jTree?

Tags: java, registry

I am using java swing.I want to show windows registry in jTree how it is possible.I am new in java please give me a solution.Actually i want to delete a particular windows registry key i done it but i can not show it in jtree means i show the structure before regkey deletion and after deletion.

Comment: @abs - you should  add comments to answers instead of editing your question. As you are a new user, I have added the comment for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, and wasn't able to find something ready-to-use. After some reading I wrote a TreeModel implementing class to do this. 
Class can be used to convert any TreePath list into tree, eg:

```
A->B->C->D
A->B->E->F
A->G->H->J
```

will become:

```
A+
 |B+
 | |C+
 | | |D
 | |E+
 |   |F
 |G+
   |H+
     |J
```

Here it is:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
    import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
    import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

    /**
     *
     * @author Majkel
     */
    public class TreePathsTreeModel implements TreeModel {
      private final ArrayList<TreePath> paths;
      private final String root;

      public TreePathsTreeModel(String root, TreePath[] paths) {
        this.root = root;
        this.paths = new ArrayList<TreePath> (Arrays.asList(paths));
      }


      @Override
      public Object getRoot() {
        return this.root;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        try {
          return getChildren(parent).get(index);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
          return null;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        return getChildren(parent).size();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
          TreePath treePath = paths.get(i);
          if (treePath.getLastPathComponent().equals(node))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }

      // This method is only required for editable trees, so it is not
      // implemented here.
      @Override
      public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

      @Override
      public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        return getChildren(parent).indexOf(child);
      }

      // This TreeModel never fires any events (since it is not editable)
      // so event listener registration methods are left unimplemented
      @Override
      public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

      @Override
      public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
              //search all paths in list for given object 
              //return every item one level further than it
      private ArrayList<String> getChildren(Object parent) {
        ArrayList<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.paths.size(); i++) {
          ArrayList<Object> pathObjects = new ArrayList<Object>( Arrays.asList(this.paths.get(i).getPath()) );
          for (Iterator<Object> it = pathObjects.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Object parentCandidate = it.next();
            if (parentCandidate.equals(parent)) {
              Iterator<Object> checker = it;
              try {
                String child = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( checker.next() ).toString();
                if ( !children.contains(child) )
                  children.add (child);
              } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {

              } 
            }
          }
        }
        return children;
      }

    }
```

It is vulnerable to duplicate entries, eg:

```
A->B->C->D
A->C->E->F
A->G->H->J
```

will become:

```
 A+
  |B+
  | |C+
  |   |D
  |   |E+
  |     |F
  |C+
  | |D
  | |E+
  |   |F
  |G+
    |H+
      |J
```

Maybe I'll fix it later, or maybe someone has an idea how to do it?
An example use:

```
TreePath tpOne = new TreePath(new String [] {"A", "B", "C", "D"});
TreePath tpTwo = new TreePath(new String [] {"A", "B", "E", "F"});
TreePath tpThree = new TreePath(new String [] {"A", "G", "H", "J"});

TreeModel model = new TreePathsTreeModel("A", TreePath[]{tpOne, tpTwo, tpThree}  );
JTree tree = new JTree(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "[read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)"

**Update:**
To display the registry in a [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) you will need to provide a [TreeModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html).

I would start with the [FileSystemModel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/src/FileSystemModel.txt) from [Oracle's Understanding the TreeModel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/jtree/) and replace the File calls with calls into the registry library you are using.

The win32 registry can be quite large, so you'll probably need to add a [TreeExpansionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeExpansionListener.html) to release branches that have been closed. Here's an [Oracle article on tree expansion listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treeexpansionlistener.html).

Comment: I know this post and read this code by this i can read and write by following this i can also delete registry but by this procedure i cann't show this is jTree.Actually my question is how can i show windows registry in jTree........please reply.

Comment: @kleopatra - it took me some time myself to figure out that *I just posted the comment* @abc tried to add to the answer by editing the answer. *(reminder to self, don't do that)*