# How to build a Serializable TreeModel containing files and subdirectories?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, treemodel

I'm trying to build a `TreeModel` for a Java application. Since I need to serialize it and send it via an `ObjectOutputStream`, I'm trying to use the `DefaultTreeModel` because it implements the `Serializable` interface.

Ok, I think I'm fine with that.

**My question is**: Now, how can I build a `DefaultTreeModel` containing a directory (passed as argument, a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` I guess ?) and all its files and subdirectories ?

I achieved that with a `JTree` but it seems not to be Serializable so now I'm stucked because I'm unable to understand the doc examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` is `Serializable`, and a `FileTreeModel` that implements `TreeModel` is straightforward, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513). You can traverse a tree rooted in `File f` using code like this:

```
private void ls(File f) { 
    File[] list = f.listFiles();
    for (File file : list) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) ls(file);
        else handle(file);
    }
}
```

Also consider Bloch's suggestion, [Item 75](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137150021?portal=informit), "Do not accept the default serialized form without first considering whether it is appropriate."

Comment: I do not want to traverse anything, I just need a TreeModel (like your FileTreeModel example) that I can build by passing a root directory, and Serialize (what your example doesn't seem to do). As simple as that. Nothing else.

Comment: Then just add `implements Serializable` and a `static final long` field named `serialVersionUID`. The single attribute, `root`, is already `Serializable`.

Comment: Fine ! I tried it already but I was facing something strange so I wasn't certain if it was my `TreeModel` or not. I persevered with this (yours) solution and found out the bug was due something else. So now it's working, thank you !