# How to pass an FTP server's directory structure through a socket and display it in Client's GUI using JTree

Tags: java, swing, sockets, network-programming, jtree

I am creating an FTP application in JAVA, to transfer files between a server and clients. I have created a GUI for the Client which should display the clients directory structure on the left and the server's on the right, but I am unable to figure out how to pass the directory structure of the server and display it on the client's GUI. I have tried passing it as an object from the server and reading it on the client side, but can't figure out how to pass it to the server's JTree. However I am able to display the clients directory structure on the GUI. I have tried looking around for solutions but can't find any that would help in my case. Any help would really be appreciated.

Below are the classes that I am using. I am only using a simple client and server class for now, which sends a message to each other when the connection is established:

This is my server class:

```
public class SimpleServer {

    public FileSystemModel systemModel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleServer s = new SimpleServer();
        s.run();
    }

    public void run() throws IOException{
        ServerSocket serverSoc = new ServerSocket(150);
        System.out.println("Server up and running on port 150");
        Socket soc = serverSoc.accept();

        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        ps.println("Welcome");

        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);

        //Not sure if this works
        ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        String dir = "C:/Users/David/Desktop/Server/";
        systemModel = new FileSystemModel(new File(dir));
        oOut.writeObject(systemModel);

        /*if (message != null){
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            ps.println("Message Received");
        }*/
    }
}
```

This is my client class:

```
public class SimpleClient {

    Socket soc;

    public void run() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        soc = new Socket("localhost", 150);

        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

        String message = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);

        if (message != null) {
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            ps.println("Message Received");
        }
    }

    //Not sure if this method is working
    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        Object model = oIn.readObject();
        return model;
    }
}
```

This class is used in my GUI to display the directory structure in JTree. Only able to display client's directory structure at the moment.

```
class FileSystemModel implements TreeModel, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private File root;

    private Vector<TreeModelListener> listeners = new Vector<TreeModelListener>();

    public FileSystemModel(File rootDirectory) {
        root = rootDirectory;
    }

     //All the other implemented methods from TreeModel goes here


    private void fireTreeNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices,
            Object[] children) {
        TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices,
                children);
        Iterator<TreeModelListener> iterator = listeners.iterator();
        TreeModelListener listener = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            listener = iterator.next();
            listener.treeNodesChanged(event);
        }
    }

    private class TreeFile extends File {
        /**
     * 
     */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5775093232151119831L;

        public TreeFile(File parent, String child) {
            super(parent, child);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is my GUI class which displays two JTrees. The client's directory structure on the left and the server's on the right, which I am having problem displaying:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private FileSystemModel systemModel;
    private SimpleClient c;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public GUI() throws Exception {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        //Connect Button
        JMenuItem mntmConnect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
        mntmConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                c = new SimpleClient();
                try {
                    c.run();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        });

        mnFile.add(mntmConnect);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        contentPane.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        String dir = "C:/Users/David/Desktop/Client/";

        systemModel = new FileSystemModel(new File(dir));

        final JTree treeClient = new JTree(systemModel);
        treeClient.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent arg0) {
                File file = (File) treeClient.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                //fileDetailsTextArea.setText(getFileDetails(file));
                System.out.println(getFileDetails(file));
            }
        });
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(treeClient);

        //This is where I want to pass the server's directory structure
        JTree treeServer = new JTree();
        splitPane.setRightComponent(treeServer);    
    }

    private String getFileDetails(File file) {
        // returns details of the file clicked
    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"can't figure out how to pass it to the server's JTree."*  Huh?  Why is the local file-system on the user's PC of relevance to the server?  You do realize the server might be headless, right?  That would mean it cannot actually create a `JTree`.

Comment: I was just trying if I could do it that way. I am not very familiar with using GUI's and not got much knowledge about JTree and TreeModel. I want to write a method on server's side to pass may be a JTree object and use that on the GUI, but can't figure out how to.

Answer (score 1):

You can send objects through serialization from one socket to another. Just send your tree model over. Note that DefaultMutableTreeNode implements Serializable.

I wouldn't send File objects over (although that is also Serializable), only Strings. Also there is no need to send a TreeModel instance, it is enough to send a DefaultMutableTreeNode, you can build your TreeModel on the receiving side. Just make sure that your object-graph contains only Serializable objects.

Comment: I did think about that, but couldn't figure out how to write the method.

Comment: I am only a JAVA beginner, so if you could point me towards an example that would be really helpful and I can can create my own method then.

Comment: Here is an example for sending objects through serialization over a socket: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/ServerSocketandSocketforSerializableobject.htm

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to mount the remote file system locally, as suggested here for [Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/149385/map-ftp-server-as-a-local-drive-in-finder) or [Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/6079/how-can-i-mount-an-ftp-to-a-drive-letter-in-windows). Then  you can create a `TreeModel` using `File`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513).

Comment: Well I guess if he can just mount the remote filesystem, then he does not need to create a graphical file transfer program at all...