# Binding HashMap<String, String> to MutableTreeNode

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

I need to bind a `Hashmap` to a `MutableTreeNode` so that I can display that in a `JTree`.

I have the following code:

```
static Map<String, String> form = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
```

I guess this is how I need to implement `MutableTreeNode`. I just don't know how to procees now to get the Key's of "form" to show up in the `MutableTreeNode`.

```
public class MyNode implements MutableTreeNode {

    @Override
    public Enumeration children() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAllowsChildren() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeNode getChildAt(int childIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIndex(TreeNode node) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeNode getParent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(MutableTreeNode arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void remove(MutableTreeNode arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void removeFromParent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setParent(MutableTreeNode arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserObject(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

After the `MutableTreeNode` correctly shows the correct `Key` value, I want to be able to do:

```
final JTree tree = new JTree();
final DefaultMutableTreeNode CustomNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Custom");
DefaultTreeModel tm = new DefaultTreeModel(CustomNode);
tree.setModel(tm);

for (String str : form.keySet())
        {
          MyNode nod = new MyNode(str);
          CustomNode.add(node);           
        }
tm.reload();
```

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: what is difficult to understand in _naming conventions_?

Comment: what is wrong in my question?

Comment: shaking head and gritting teeth: see my first comment (hint: it's an advice you _should_ follow ... implication being that you don't ;)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a custom implementation of the `TreeModel` interface. As noted in [*How to Use Trees: Creating a Data Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data),

> The `TreeModel` interface accepts any kind of object as a tree node. It does not require that nodes be represented by `DefaultMutableTreeNode` objects, or even that nodes implement the `TreeNode` interface.

Although your `Map<String, String>` is not intrinsically hierarchical, you may get an idea from the `GenealogyModel`, cited [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg), or the [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).