# Choosing between a custom tree model or default tree model when insert/removing nodes and updating tree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a set of nodes for a command-line application and would like to put a GUI over it. I want to display the tree visually and am using a `JTree`. I have written my own tree model that implements the `TreeModel` interface and the tree is rendered as expected.

But now I want to be able to insert or remove nodes. Currently I am just redrawing the tree whenever I perform an insert or remove operation, which is a terrible solution especially if there are thousands of nodes.

The `DefaultTreeModel` handles all of the inserting and removing and tree updating as required. I would have to figure out how that works for my own model.

The sole reason for using a custom tree model is just so that I can work with the existing nodes objects. Is this reason "good enough" to implement a custom model or should I look for a way to use the default mutable tree node objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in [*How to Use Trees: Creating a Data Model*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data), "the `TreeModel` interface accepts any kind of object as a tree node." Your custom `TreeModel` can efficiently reflect your "pre-existing hierarchical data structure."

As a concrete example, look at the [`FileTreeModel`](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692). The only thing missing is the `TreeModelListener` plumbing, instructions for which are found in the [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) API.

Addendum: Regarding rendering efficiency, `JTree` uses the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to render only visible nodes. Firing the appropriate `TreeModelEvent` in your `TreeModel` will allow the listing tree to react to changes in the model. `DefaultTreeModel` is a useful guide.

Comment: +1... @Keikoku just to point out have a look at trashgods first link (*How to Use Trees: Creating a Data Model*) especially at [Dynamically Changing a Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic) if I understood the question

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: Good point; more above on the rendering aspect of the question.

Comment: +1 if I could again ! your insight behind the actual code makes me question how much I really think i know :)