# Java File Tree Error (FileTreeModel cannot be resolved to a type)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, tree, compiler-errors

I've used a piece of code from this question ([Java JTree directory structure from file paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831901/java-jtree-directory-structure-from-file-paths/14837208#14837208)). But when I use it, I get an error: 'FileTreeModel cannot be resolved to a type'. I use eclipse, and have the last SDK. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Mathijs

```
TreeModel model = new FileTreeModel(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
JTree tree = new JTree(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `FileTreeModel.java` from the compilation path as presented [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-)